# How to get the name of a jQuery UI widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I need a way to read the name of a jQuery UI widget. I have subclassed the `dialog` widget into two subclasses, `myDialog1` and `myDialog2`. I have created a `destroyDialog` function to destroy whichever dialog is active. There should be a way to determine the name of the widget instance.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
var destroyDialog = function() {
    activeDialog[activeDialog.widgetName]("destroy");
}
```

But I don't see a way to get the widget name. For now I'm using ugly nested try-catch statements.

```
var destroyDialog = function() {
        try {
            activeDialog.dialog("destroy");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                activeDialog.myDialog1("destroy");
            }
            catch (e) {
                activeDialog.myDialog2("destroy");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the widget name (and use it) by using

```
activeDialog.data("widgetName");
```

... as tdmartin refers to.  So therefore:

```
activeDialog[activeDialog.data("widgetName")]("destroy");
```

But to get around this problem personally, I have written a plugin that will allow you to call a widget method without knowing what *type* the widget is.  This will allow you to do:

```
activeDialog.callWidgetMethod('destroy');
```

It relies on you using jQuery UI 1.11+.  If you are using <1.11, you can take out the *"Skip this widget if it does not have the method"* check, but the downside of that is that you will get an error if you attempt to call a method that a widget does not have.

**Plugin code**:

```
jQuery.fn.callWidgetMethod = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    var result = null;
    if(!this || !this.length) 
        return this;

    this.each(function (i,o) {
        var compClass = $(this).data("widgetName");
        var func = $(this)[compClass];
        // Skip this element if it does not appear to be an initialised jQuery widget
        if(!compClass || !func)
            return true;

        // Skip this widget if it does not have the method (the name of which will be in args[0])
        // This relies on the 'instance' method provided in jQuery UI 1.11
        if(args.length>1 && !$(this)[compClass]("instance")[args[0]])
            return true;

        result = func.apply($(this),args);
    });

    if(this.length>1) 
        return this;
    else 
        return result;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you standardize your namespace you could use a regex to match the name of the variable where your widget instance is stored (the name of the widget), returned by the [$().data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
for (i in $(<your element>).data() ) {
    if (i.match(/dialog/)) {
        $(<your element>).data(i).destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but my two "subclassed" widgets aren't instances of $.ui.dialog, but are their own widgets that inherit methods from dialog. $(this).dialog() throws an error - it needs $(this).myDialog1() or $(this).myDialog2(), which is why I need to know how to get the widget name.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not understand what you were doing. If you do $(<your element>).data(); it will return an object with all the jqueryUi specific data, one of the elements in that object is your widget name (camelCased if the name of your widget has a dot in it, like activeDialogMyDialog2). You can name your widgets in a way that it is easy to get them.